# Is an empty id or null id good HTML practice? Conditionally adding an id to html element

Tags: html, dom, accessibility, jsx

My goal is to conditionally add an id to an html element. In JSX, I have this conundrum of conditionally adding an id to an html element as so:

```
<SomeHTMLElement id={condition ? "someId" : ""} />
```

or

```
<SomeHTMLElement id={condition ? "someId" : null} />
```

Which method is better HTML practice? Defaulting to `null` or `""`?

If there is another way to conditionally add an id to an HTML element without even introducing the id attribute to the element itself, that would also be great. e.g. `<HTMLElement id />` or `<HTMLElement id="" />` or `<HTMLElement id={null} />` would be best to not have the empty `id` attribute there so it would be compiled to `<HTMLElement />`

Comment: Why does this element need an ID? What significance does the ID have?

Comment: Neither is good practice. Either give the item a unique id or don't give it an `id` attribute at all.

Comment: @KevinB I have a leaf-node component that receives data to use as an `id`. For some consumers of this leaf-node component, they will not be passing in an `id` attribute so it can default to `""` or null at times

Comment: If it's just data you're passing around, maybe `id` isn't the right tool.

Comment: `{condition ? "someId" : \`_${(Math.random()*100).toString(32).replace(/\W/g, '')}\`}`

Comment: I'd suggest a `data` attribute instead, e.g. `data-id`.

Comment: I believe JSX has a `if` block construction, doesn't it? Just have something that checks for the condition and only adds the id attribute if it is present.

Answer (score 2):

Empty ID attributes are bad practice, because they are invalid HTML. If you don't need an ID attribute in the DOM, then don't output it at all.

The following HTML document contains an `id` attribute with no value, and and `id=""` attribute with an explicit empty string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Empty ID validation test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Empty ID validation test</h1>

    <p id>This paragraph has an id attribute without a value.</p>
    <p id="">This paragraph has an id attribute explicitly set to an empty string.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

The W3C validator gives two different errors about this.

1. "Bad value for attibute `id` on element `p`: An ID must not be an empty string." The validator gives this error for both of the `id` attributes in this example.
2. "Duplicate ID".  IDs must be unique, but the validator sees `id` and `id=""` as having the same value.

Note that duplicate IDs are also an explicit failure of WCAG at level A (see [F77: Failure of Success Criterion 4.1.1 due to duplicate values of type ID](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/F77)), though in practice [this doesn't cause accessibility harm unless the ID is being referred to by an IDREF elsewhere](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2015/11/wcag-2-0-parsing-criterion-is-a-pita/).

In JSX, I believe setting an attribute to the `null` value (e.g. `<HTMLElement id={null} />`) is an easy way to prevent it appearing in the DOM. Note I'm talking about the actual DOM here, not a virtual DOM.